# Why the color became bright after rendering?

Tags: rendering, light, color, shadows

Would you tell me how can I fix it?
The first image is screenshot of render preview and the second one is after rendering. As you can see, it became bright after rendering.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Quite a few possible reasons.. maybe share a stripped-down version of your world, the minimum that shows the effect, on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ?

Comment: Remember, if you have any lights in your scene that you have hidden in viewport view, will still appear in the render. Be sure to check and see if this is the case. I've spent many an hour wondering where the "extra" light is coming from because of this.

Comment: Oh yes you're right! It was because hidden light...
Thank you so much!!